# Reload ember model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

Hi I'm a little confused how ember works, I've got a app I'm creating which is to list tasks for a particular user. Here is my model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    archive: DS.attr('boolean'),
    user: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

That is for when i add a task to the task list. However for when I get all the tasks in my tasklist i use this in my route:

```
model: function () {    
        return this.store.findAll('task');   
    }
```

For my filtering of all the users for the tasks I've add this to my controller:

```
filteredModel: Ember.computed('model', function(){
        let model = this.get('model');

        return model.filter(function(item){
            return item.data.user == this.get('session.user.email');
        });

    }),
```

All of this works fine. However when I add a new task to the task list, it doesnt update my tasks list, so I have to reload my page. Can this be done automatically, without refreshing my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array returned by `findAll` is a live array and will always contain all records in the store. However your CP has a wrong dependency key. The dependency key should either include `.[]` or `.@each.?`, or it won't listen on array changes. Because you use the `user` property it should be `model.@each.user`. Also you probably should add the current user to the dependency key.

Finally your CP can't work at all, because the `this` in the filter function is the `this` of the filter function, not the Controller. You should either use an arrow function or save the `this` to a variable.

Also `item.data.user` seems wrong, probably this should be `item.get('user')`.

So the final CP is:

```
filteredModel: Ember.computed('model.@each.user', 'session.user.email', function(){
    return this.get('model')
        .filter(item => item.get('user') == this.get('session.user.email'));
}),
```

Comment: Hi Lux I've got another issue regarding ember would you be able to check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276924/ember-js-nested-forms

Comment: Maybe you should checkout the ember slack help channel for more discussion like questions.